# EmberJS: contentBinding not working

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ember.js

Whats wrong here? Why does the contentBinding in the view dont work?

Output
**content in view undefined**

router.coffee

```
App.Router.map ->
  @route "show"
  @route "intro",
```

intro_controller.coffee

```
App.IntroController = Ember.ArrayController.extend

  content: []

  createRecords:(files) ->
    @set('content', Ember.A())

    person = Ember.Object.create(username: "hello world")
    @pushObject person
    console.info "content in controller", @get('content')

    @transitionTo 'show'
```

show_view.coffee

```
App.ShowView = Ember.View.extend

  contentBinding: 'App.IntroController.content',

  didInsertElement: ->
    console.info "content in view", @get('content')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `App.IntroController` is a subclass of `Ember.Object`, not an instance.

You need a `App.ShowController` that specifies what it *needs*:

```
App.ShowController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['intro']
});
```

And then in the view you will have access to: `controllers.intro.content`.